# Init issue in BF548 EZkit

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, init

What is the reason behind kernel can not get **init** file though this file present in target architecture?

i am working on BF548 EZKIT, And completed NOR boot Mode. But In NAND boot mode I had flash `u-boot.ldr` , `uImage` and `rootfs.jffs2` file on specified mtdblocks on specific address, during boot my kernel loaded successfully, mounted rootfs successfully, and after that gives error

```
VFS: Mounted root (jffs2 filesystem) on device 31:9.

devtmpfs: error mounting -2

Freeing unused kernel memory: 140K (003b4000 - 003d7000)

Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
```

Also i had tried `init=/sbin/init` and other init options in kernel command line but none of them work.

Comment: How do you know it is "present"? Did you confirm that the mounting was indeed done correctly?

Comment: Can you instruct me how can i confirm that? And i had checked target folder created in "/output/" directory and in "/target/sbin/" directory i confirm that there is "init" available , and also i had generate jffs2 filesystem manually using "mkfs.jffs2" but no luck and same error.